# AMP - POST with `content-type: application/json`

Tags: amp-html

## The problem

Is it possible to send a POST request with `Content-Type: application/json` on AMP applications?

## More context

I have a form on my App and I need to perform a POST request on my API with `Content-type: application/json`. I've checked the [amp-form](https://www.ampproject.org/pt_br/docs/reference/components/amp-form) component in order to do it, but I've noticed that it sends a request with the header `content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryoYJsC0JKaBczGL1z` as you may see [here](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-form%2Fsource%2F).

[image]

So, is it possible to change this to `application/json` or the API needs to handle the `content-type: multipart/form-data;` requests as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the API to handle it. The fetch event [seems to always going to have multipart/form-data](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/src/service/xhr-impl.js#L223).

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

I've checked the [link](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-form%2Fsource%2F) you've provided and I got a `content-type: application/json`.

[image: Check this image.]

Based from this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/pt_br/docs/reference/components/amp-form#success/error-response-rendering), both success and error responses should have a `Content-Type: application/json` header. `submit-success` will render for all responses that has a status of `2XX`, all other statuses will render `submit-error`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! In fact, I was asking about the REQUEST header, not the RESPONSE header. 
Nowadays my API sends a RESPONSE header with `Content-type: application/json` and everything works fine, but it doesn't handle REQUESTS which are not `Content-type: application/json`. 

Therefore, is it possible to send a POST REQUEST on AMP with a header `Content-type: application/json` instead of  `content-type: multipart/form-data;`?